# Bash for loop error

Tags: bash

I have a script in bash what take from LocLog a ip from collumn 8 :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat /scripts/logs/LocLog | awk '{print $8}' | sort | uniq); 
do 
    php /scripts/a.php $i; 
done
```

The script give an error:

```
bash -x log
'og: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `
'og: line 2: `for i in $(cat /scripts/logs/LocLog | awk '{print $8}' | sort | uniq);
```

Any ideeas?

Comment: Useless use of `cat` (and probably `uniq`): `awk '{print $8}' /scripts/logs/LocLog | sort -u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the semicolon at the end of the `for` line.